# How can I get specific item from collection? Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-criteria

I have two entities with one-to-many relationships (simplified):

```
public class Action{
   @OneToMany
   private Set<ActionDetailParameter> detailParameters = new HashSet<>(0);
}
```

```
public class ActionDetailParameter {
   private String parameterName;
   private String parameterValue;
}
```

I need to select all Actions where detailParameters item has **parameterName** equals **"newserviceDepartmentName"**. I tried using this code:

```
...
SetJoin<Action, ActionDetailParameter> detailParameters = actionRoot.joinSet("detailParameters", JoinType.LEFT);
Predicate namePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(detailParameters.get("parameterName"), "newserviceDepartmentName");

QueryBuildingCriteria<Action> queryBuildingCriteria = getQueryBuildingCriteria(Action.class);
CriteriaQuery<Action> query = (CriteriaQuery<Action>) queryBuildingCriteria.getQuery();
getResultList(createQuery(query.select(actionRoot).where(namePredicate)));
...
```

there was the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.parameterName' [select generatedAlias0 from common.dao.entities.Action as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias1.parameterName=:param0]
```

please tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem to be that you construct a new `CriteriaQuery` after creating the `actionRoot`. As you don't show the whole code, this is some speculation.

```
QueryBuildingCriteria<Action> queryBuildingCriteria = getQueryBuildingCriteria(Action.class);
CriteriaQuery<Action> query = (CriteriaQuery<Action>) queryBuildingCriteria.getQuery();
```

I have adjusted your mapping to something I had existing in my system and have simply replaced the working classes/field names with the ones from your question:

```
public void test() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getSessionFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Action> createQuery = cb.createQuery(Action.class);
    Root<Action> x = createQuery.from(Action.class);
    createQuery.select(x)
            .where(cb.equal(x.joinList("detailParameters").get("parameterName"),
                    "newserviceDepartmentName"));
    List<Action> resultList = getSession().createQuery(createQuery).getResultList();
    System.out.println(resultList);
}
```

This should return all `Action`s which have an `ActionDetailParameter` where the `parameterName` equals `newserviceDepartmentName`